# Upload Recording from Cordova Media Plugin

Tags: cordova, upload, media, record

I am trying to upload an audio file recorded with the Cordova Media Plugin on iOS.
The audio files are created and I am able to play them back.

But I can't find a working solution to upload the recording from the file system. My code for the recording is:

```
 record = new Media(src,
            // success callback
            function () {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
            },

            // error callback
            function (err) {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: " + err.code);
            });

 // Record audio
 record.startRecord();
 //when finished
 record.stopRecord();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out how to do it:

On iOS you will have to add the Cordova File System Plugin first to create a new Entry.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

To create the record File and set the global variables fileURL and audioRecord:

```
    //Prepares File System for Audio Recording
    audioRecord = 'record.wav';
    onDeviceReady();

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(audioRecord, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();
    }
```

to start and stop the record:

```
 record = new Media(audioRecord,
            // success callback
            function () {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Succes: ");
            },

            // error callback
            function (err) {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: " + err.code);
            });

        // Record audio
        record.startRecord();
        // Wait
        record.stopRecord();
```

To upload the file you will first have to add the File Transfer Plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

Then you can call this method to upload the record:

```
//Method to upload Audio file to server
var uploadAudio = function () {
    var win = function (r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = "recordupload.wav";
    options.mimeType = "audio/wav";

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://yoururl.com/uploadaudio.php"), win, fail, options);
}
```

To receive the file you can use this PHP script:

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "records/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Comment: The upload is working but the file is corrupt. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620656/php-file-transfer-not-uploading-video-to-server Need your assitance. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileTransfer plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md. To install do:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

then do this

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();

var success = function (r) {
    // success code here
};
var fail = function (error) {
    // failure code here
    alert('File could not be uploaded');
};

options.fileKey = 'image'; // set the key for the server to know where the cotent is
options.fileName = '/myfile.jpg'; // location of your file
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg"; // mimeType

params.myParam = 'My Value'; // add other parameters if required

options.params = params;
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI('/path/to/my/post/handler'), success, fail, options);
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem here is to get the correct location of the audio file.

Comment: it should be just `src`

Comment: @unobf, the upload is working but the file is corrupt. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @Ionut what mime type are you using?

Comment: I'm uploading an audio file. The mimetype is audio/AMR. I've also tried audio/mpeg for mp3. When I convert the amr file to an mp3 file with an online converter tool the audio works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: I am not sure, but that is showing that the upload is not corrupting the file. It must be some other bug like the player not understanding the format or incorrectly identifying the format