# php: file transfer not uploading video to server

Tags: php, cordova

I am using cordova file transfer plugin to upload video to my webserver. Below is the code of front end.

```
var uri = encodeURI("https://www.abc.xyz/app/upload_vid.php");

        fileURL = "file://"+filefromgallery;
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="video/mp4";
        options.chunkedMode = false;

           options.headers = {
               Connection: "close"
            };

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
            } else {
                loadingStatus.increment();
            }
        };
        ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options);
}
```

Here is the back end code.

```
    $dirname = "./video";
$filename = 'test';
        if ($_FILES) {
            print_r($_FILES);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["name"]["tmp_name"],$dirname."/".$filename.'.mp4');
        }
```

I did some debugging today.
here is the output of `print_r($_FILES);`

```
Response = Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => video-name-here.mp4
            [type] => video/mp4
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJzw3UB
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 479000
        )

)

<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>/home/u966130057/public_html/model_app/upload_vid.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />

In Console debug i am getting below error for frontend.
Uncaught ReferenceError: loadingStatus is not defined
    at FileTransfer.ft.onprogress (index.js:214)
    at win (FileTransfer.js:159)
    at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)
    at <anonymous>:1:283
```

Comment: Use `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`, though you might want to handle errors abit better in the php.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Just updated the code. Have a look.

Comment: try `$_FILES['file']['name']` for the name and `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` for the path.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Are you sure because in option.filekey= "name" is defined.

Comment: I'm basing it off of your PHP output, I don't know about some Javascript uploaded. I just us Iframes targeted by a normal form for that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I tried your code but i am getting error code 3.

Comment: What to you mean `my code`.  thats just how you look it up.  if you want code try this `echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: I mean your suggestion. If you look dump which i have added in the end of question. It will give you more details.